# How to change the font of the header and footer of print page with CSS?

Tags: css, printing

How can I change the font of the **default** header and footer of print page with CSS?

I tried this:

```
@media print
 {
     *,html,body,title /*i tried all of them!*/
     {
         font: 10px tahoma;
     }
 }
```

The content of body was changed,
but no change was happened in font of print page title, URL and pagination.(ctrl+p)

This is my print page image to clear my question:

[image]

Comment: The title is usually outside of the body (traditionally in the head section). Try either `html {font: 10px tahoma; }` or `title{font: 10px tahoma;}`

Comment: The problem is not in your code. It's probably the rest of the html/css. I just tested in jsfiddle. Add color:red just to see if it changes the color. You do know you have to test it by pressing Ctrl+P, right? Or by actually printing it.

Comment: @gaynorvader are you trying to change the font of the `<title>` tag?

Comment: Please add the HTML code to your question.

Comment: In short: you can't, sorry.
A bit longer: the @page context used by browsers to print documents does not know nothing about fonts but only aabout a very short set of rules/stuff that you can see yourself at http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/page.html

Comment: According to friends, this is not possible! Thanks...

Answer (score -3):

The answer to your question depends on which HTML element contains the header and footer in the page you are trying to print. Check to make sure that the header and footer are between the body tags (`<body></body>`).